# StateObject's optional properties with TextFields

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a FormView with a `StateObject` whose properties I'm binding to textfields (hopefully two-way binding)

### Form View

```
struct FormView: View {
    
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                TextField("name", text: $viewModel.user.name)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .font(.system(size: 16))
    ...
```

### User

```
struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String?

    init(id: Int) {
        self.id = id
    }
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // I had it as `User?` but `View` doesn't like it, so had to hardcode a default value
    @Published var user: User = User(id: 0) 
    ...
}
```

### Error

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding'

### Attempt

```
 // tried to assign default values

TextField("Name", text: $viewModel.user.name ?? "")
```

**Question,**

How to resolve the optional problem: I can't have all the properties non-optional and even the User object can be optional.

How to bind optional properties to textfields

### Attempt 2

This worked for me.

```
TextField("Name", text: Binding(
    get: { observable.user.name ?? "" },
    set: { observable.user.name = $0 }))
    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    .font(.system(size: 16))
```

Comment: Same issue even without the $ sign,

Comment: Consider to avoid optionals in SwiftUI as much as possible. Why is `name`optional at all? A user who maybe has a name is very unlikely.

Comment: correct, i came across issue for a different field, quickly used `name` to reproduce a quick example.

Comment: It's not worth it to fight the framework. In case of a string checking for `.empty` is quite the same as checking for `nil`.

Comment: @vadian sure, I like what you said, but can you please give me an example with the code answer so I understand what you said.

Comment: I simply mean to declare `name` as non-optional – which can be seamlessly bound to the text field –  and add a computed property `var hasName : Bool { !name.isEmpty }`. Then, rather than checking `if let name = user.name {...` you can check `if user.hasName {…`

Comment: I see, it's not the name actually, there are bunch of other properties, i just used name for the lack of a better name, i have other optional properties and can't have computed properties for each one.

Comment: In SwiftUI the `View` struct is a view model already you don't need another object. `@StateObject` is for when you need `@State` to hold a reference type.

Comment: `var name: String = ""` problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are seeing has to do with the Optional String Binding you are trying to pass into the TextField. TextField is expecting a String Binding (even if its empty), so to get that to be valid, you need the `name` of the User to be non-optional OR you need to create a Binding from an optional String.

You can do this in a few ways, but one quick way would be to create an extension that does it for us:

```swift
extension Binding where Value == String? {
    func orEmpty() -> Binding<String> {
        return .init(
            get: { self.wrappedValue ?? "" },
            set: { self.wrappedValue = $0 }
        )
    }
}
```

That should be enough to let you use it in your TextField like so:

```swift
TextField("Placeholder", text: $viewModel.user.name.orEmpty())
```

---

Also, as a side note I would mention that your ViewModel holds a User, so you should be injecting it. I imagine at some point, you will be able to either select different users, or maybe you are going into a specific View that adjust the User information. If you update your ViewModel, you can accept a user in like so:

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user: User
    
    init(user: User = User(id: 123)) {
        self.user = user
    }
}
```

And finally, your View can then be initialized with a ViewModel. This means that you would create the ViewModel before you are shown the FormView so that the data you are manipulating is coming from the Model (or the source of truth):

```swift
struct FormView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    ...
}
```

All of this should get you to the point where whenever you want to see the FormView, all you need to do is get the User and pass it in - or if you are creating a user, you can have it have default values:

**New User:**

```swift
FormView(viewModel: ViewModel())
```

**Existing User:**

```swift
FormView(viewModel: ViewModel(user: existingUser)
```

Comment: Please see Edit #2

Comment: Im glad that you figured out how to get the optional in your textfield. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks, I've a problem with the `PickerView` with custom objects. `struct Department` with an `id`, and `name`, do you know any existing answer?

Comment: Are you able to post your code so I can see it?

Comment: give me a few, and I'll link

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566098/uipicker-with-a-custom-class-in-swiftui

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject

Comment: Yeah, the `StateObject` would probably make more sense to be created earlier in your flow and passed through to the other Views as an `ObservedObject` like the apple documentation @loremipsum provided. I think in this case, a simple ObservedObject should be used. I updated my answer to better align with the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because the `name` is not a binding value, the `User` struct is a binding value so it can't resolve that. To fix it you need to make the text `Bindable`.

```
class TestUser: ObservableObject {       // Change struct to class
    @Published var name = "John, Doe"
}
 
class TestVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var testUser = TestUser()
}
 
struct PlaygroundView: View {
    @StateObject var testVM = TestVM()
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Hello, World", text: $testVM.testUser.name)
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm still using `@StateObject` here, so it is two-way binding.
A few other things to note.

#### Structs vs Classes

Structs are non-mutable, meaning you can't directly change a property that exists on a struct unless it is marked `@State` or `@Binding`. The wrapper `@Published` cannot be added to a struct because it cannot be an `ObservableObject`. Classes, conversely, are `"Reference Types"`, which means when you pass them around through args/params, you're getting a reference to the real object in memory. They are mutable, and their properties can be changed. They can also contain `@Published` properties, if it's marked `ObservableObject`.

#### @Published vs @State vs @Binding

`@Published` - exists only on `class` objects, which are `observable`.
`@State` - Exists on a struct, and updates the view based on the value being updated by the view or model. This will trigger a view redraw.
`@Binding` - Same functionality as `@State` but you would pass an `@State` in args/params, so that the consuming view/object can update a parent, yet maintain it's own state.

#### @StateObject vs @ObservedObject

`@StateObject` is intended to indicate ownership of the observable object. When you mark a property with @StateObject, SwiftUI will create and exclusively manage the lifecycle of the object, much in the way it does for @State.

*Remember, @StateObject should be used only for objects that are owned by this view.*

`@ObservedObject`, on the other hand, merely establishes a connection to an observable object without implying ownership. The object in question is expected to be created and owned elsewhere in your program, not within the view that observes it. Because if you use this, it lacks ownership, when you update from your view it will not explicitly update the same way that @State would. Only when the owning object updates it would it then update any views that use is. Ergo why it gives the appearance of `one-way`.

Final Note:

- The property wrappers can be passed by using `Binding<Type>` such as `Binding<Int>`. You can use that anywhere you'd normally use it such as an initializer. Sometimes you might run into an issue where you pass an `Binding<Any>` as a parameter and you need to set it to a bound value, or initial value for State. You can use `Binding(initialValue: _)` or `State(initialValue: _)` or `Published(InitialValue: _)` to accommodate initialization w/ those wrapped properties.

Comment: This doesn't actually resolve the issue of `user` and `user.name` being optional - the root cause of OP's issue.

Comment: Please see Edit #2

Comment: Gentlemen, please help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77566098/uipicker-with-a-custom-class-in-swiftui