# Picker with a Custom class in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `Department` struct on the `User` object as an optional field.

### Department

```
struct Department: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    
    var id: Int
    var name: String?
    
    init(id: Int, name: String? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

### User

Minimalist example: User object with an optional field of the Department

```
struct User: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {
    
    var id: Int
    var department: Department?
    
    init(id: Int, department:Department? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.department = department
    }
    
}
```

### ViewModel

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
     
    @Published var user: User = User(id: 0) // default value but gets updated as a result of a network call. I attempted with optional first but SwiftUI didn't like it. 
    
    @Published var departments: [Department] = [Department(id: 0, name: "--NoneSelected--")] // initial list with one item, but gets populated via network call

....
```

### View

```
Picker(selection: $viewModel.user.department, label: Text("")) {
    ForEach(viewModel.departments, id: \.id) { department in
        Text(department.name ?? "").tag(department)
    }
}
.pickerStyle(WheelPickerStyle())
.padding()
```

List of Departments are coming from `viewModel.departments`
User department and therefore, picker selection should be `viewModel.user.department`

**Works:** Departments are populated fine

**Doesn't Work:** User's department is not reflected on the pickerview

Comment: There is no `UIPicker` here. `UIPicker` is a UIKit component. You have a SwiftUI `Picker`. (Technically, under the hood it may be a `UIPicker` when SwiftUI resolves the component, but I still think the title is misleading here)

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I have updated the title.

Comment: You are lying to the compiler by providing an equatable conformance that says that the item is equal if its ID is the same. That is likely the cause of at least some of your issues.

Comment: You should likely just conform to `Hashable` and `Equatable` and _not_ provide your own overridden functions for the implementations.

Comment: @jnpdx understood, i have removed overriden methods, and just declared `Identifiable`, `Hashable` and `Equatable` to all my structs.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] that we can run to try to debug it?

Comment: `var name: String = ""` problem solved

Comment: @malhal It's not just the name, optionals are there for a reason, to depict missing data, if we were to provide default values for everything, then simply get rid of optional from the swift language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Departments have the possibility of being Optional on the User, you need to make sure to maintain that as the case when the data is being selected.

Inside of your `Picker` you are telling the selection to be that of the Department of the User, but since there is the possibility that a user can have no Department, we need to handle that in the Picker.

To do this, you can send through a tag as an Optional:

```swift
.tag(Optional(department))
```

Then in the Picker, we just need to handle the case that a user does not have a department set (and wont need one set):

```swift
Picker(selection: $viewModel.user.department, label: Text("")) {
    
    Text("No Department")
        .tag(nil as Department?)
    
    ForEach(viewModel.departments, id: \.self) { department in
        Text(department.name ?? "")
            .tag(Optional(department))
    }
}
```

If you want, you can also just make your array of Departments on the ViewModel optional, and then you wont need to set `Optional(department)` in the tag:

```swift
@Published var departments: [Department?] = [...]
```

Comment: ` .tag(Optional(department))` that was the key. Awesome man!